# Cell that should have DropDownList control has no controls at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdown

I'm trying to get a DropDownList to show up in a GridView in c#/asp.net. The html for the GridView contains:

```
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Initials">
                        
                        <asp:ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown" runat="server">  
                                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>  
                        </asp:ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
```

The rest of the columns are added in the c# code-behind here:

```
var RouteRow = (new RoutesTableAdapter()).GetDataBy(this.AtmId);          
                RouteGrid.DataSource = RouteRow;
                foreach (DataColumn col in RouteRow.Columns)
                {
                    BoundField field = new BoundField();
                    field.DataField = col.ColumnName;
                    field.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
                    if (!col.ColumnName.Equals("Num")) field.DataFormatString = "{0:N}";
                    RouteGrid.Columns.Add(field);
            

                }
                
                RouteGrid.DataBind();
```

After DataBind is called, there is a column named Initials, but all of the cells are empty, and trying to find the 'dropdown' control in DataRowBound returns null. I realize that making some columns in markup and some in the code-behind is probably not best practices, but I don't see why the column is still there but with no controls.

edit:

The dropdown field created in the code-behind by asp.net was still null at this point, and while FindControl works after initializing it, the column is still blank. Is there a way to make the entire TemplateField in the code-behind? Naively I expected this to work:

```
TemplateField temp = new TemplateField();
temp.ItemTemplate = dropdown;
RouteGrid.Columns.Add(temp);
```

But the second line doesn't work since DropDownList isn't an ITemplate, and casting doesn't work either.

edit 2: I've answered my own question. In the markup, `asp:ItemTemplate` should be `ItemTemplate`. I have no idea why this works.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question. In the markup, asp:ItemTemplate should be ItemTemplate. I have no idea why this works.

Comment: It works because this is the correct syntax, `ItemTemplate` is expected to be appear enclosed by `asp:TemplateField` tag. Same happen to `Columns` tag inside `asp:GridView`, it also doesn't have the prefix.